# Iterate through an array of JSON objects and display in 2 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I am having trouble displaying these 2 JSON objects to the DOM. I was to:
A) Write an array of JSON objects for 2 different people that includes several key/values and
B) Iterate through the array of objects. Create a 2-col page that displays the first person details one side and the 2nd person details on the opposite side.

I believe I was to use jQuery to display the objects to the browser window, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this task. So after a long time spent seeking an answer on the "google" and experimenting with a lot of trial and all error. I am requesting some help from those who know more--not hard--than I. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Iterate Through JSON Array Object</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media 
queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">
</script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="div0">
            <h1>Column 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="div1">
            <h1>Column 2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sabioapi2.azurewebsites.net/scripts/sabio.js"></script>
<!-- All your code goes below here-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    myObj = {
        "people": [
            {
                "firstName": "Juana"
                , "lastName": "Doe"
                , "age": 23
                , "streetAddress": "123 Main St."
                , "city": "Culver City"
                , "state": "CA"
                , "zip": 92340
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Juan"
                , "lastName": "Doe"
                , "age": 47
                , "streetAddress": "123 Main St."
                , "city": "Culver City"
                , "state": "CA"
                , "zip": 92340
            }
        ]
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < myObj.people.length; i++) {
        $("#div" + i).append("<h1>" + i + ": " + myObj.people[i] + "</h1>");
        //document.getElementById("div" + i).innerHTML += i + ": " + 
 myObj[i] + "<br>";
        //console.log(myObj.people[i]);
    }
</script>
```

*

Comment: can you show us what is you expecting as a output?

Comment: It should iterate through the two arrays and display them (keys/values) in the browser/DOM. Two columns, one array in each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the json object creation correct and your for loop is a good start, each key is a property of the person object, so in your loop do this:

```js
var myObj = {
  people: [{
      "firstName": "Juana",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 23,
      "streetAddress": "123 Main St.",
      "city": "Culver City",
      "state": "CA",
      "zip": 92340
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Juan",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 47,
      "streetAddress": "123 Main St.",
      "city": "Culver City",
      "state": "CA",
      "zip": 92340
    }
  ]
}

for (var i = 0; i < myObj.people.length; i++) {
  //Now that you are iterating the people objects, iterate the keys of the object
  for (key in myObj.people[i]) {
    //Append h1 with key name and its value
    $("#example").append("<p><b>" + key + "</b>: " + myObj.people[i][key] + "</p>");
  }
  $("#example").append("<hr />")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: Isn't that what the "i" in myObj.people[i] does--cycle through the keys? I don't get [key]. If i have to put the name of the key, I'll have to do that for every key and that defeats the purpose of iterating through the array, right?

Comment: Did you mean like this:

        `for (var i = 0; i < myObj.people.length; i++) {
            $("#div" + i).append("<h1> First Name: " + myObj.people[i].firstName + "</h1>");
            $("#div" + i).append("<h1> Last Name: " + myObj.people[i].lastName + "</h1>");`

Comment: @dairusmp I've added an example snippet to this answer which may answer your questions.